# How to replace an image with another using Office Interop Word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, docx

I've been searching for two days now and I haven't found a solution to this problem.

I'm developing a Winforms app that generates reports as Word documents `.docx`. To accomplish this, I have created a Word template (`.dotx`) that I'm using as base for the reports. I'm using Office Interop Word to fill the template with data (change the `Bookmarks` texts).

Everything is working as expected except for the images in the template. How can replace those with other images?

From my searches, I found out that `doc.InlineShapes` is a collection of all the images in the document, but for some reason `doc.InlineShapes.Count` is `0` even though I have images in the template.

I know how to insert images into the document, but that will require me to do all the tedious styling via code which I thought the template should take care of.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Images can also be part ot the `Shapes` collection. If you query that does `Count` return the expected result? FWIW there is no code equivalent to replace one image with another, so depending on what you mean by "styling" the amount of code may not be significantly different than if new images were being inserted...

Comment: @CindyMeister You're right, the template images are in the `doc.Shapes` collection. Is there a way I can dynamically copy one shape styles to another shape? I'm thinking of inserting the image via code, convert it into a shape, copy the styles of the existing (placeholder) image then remove the latter. Can this be done?

Comment: Not the way you're visualizing, I'm afraid. There's no "collective" way to copy properties. The code would need to query each, individually, and apply it to the new one... I can't remember whether a `Shape` has a Tag` property, but if it does one possibility could be to write the settings to that, read the string and "parse" it. That would be faster than querying the object model for each property. Or write the properteis for all the shapes to Custom XML Part and use that as the properties' source.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "tedious styling", what changes are you finding yourself making tp these shapes when replaced manually?

Comment: @RichMichaels width, height, aspect ratio, background style, position, floating, border, ... In MS Word, I can just select the image and select the modify image menu item and the styles will be preserved, but programmatically, I'll have to do the styling from scratch, making the template image useless. Besides, I don't even know exactly what and how many styles to copy.